# Python Plotly library for networks: how to color nodes with different colors

Tags: python, plotly

The Python Plotly library enables to [plot graphs or networks](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/networks/).

The following code (from this [link](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/networks/)) is a function that returns a dictionary with different attributes of the nodes to be drawn:

`def scatter_nodes(pos, labels=None, color=None, size=20, opacity=1):
    # pos is the dict of node positions
    # labels is a list  of labels of len(pos), to be displayed when hovering the mouse over the nodes
    # color is the color for nodes. When it is set as None the Plotly default color is used
    # size is the size of the dots representing the nodes
    #opacity is a value between [0,1] defining the node color opacity
    L=len(pos)
    trace = Scatter(x=[], y=[],  mode='markers', marker=Marker(size=[]))
    for k in range(L):
        trace['x'].append(pos[k][0])
        trace['y'].append(pos[k][1])
    attrib=dict(name='', text=labels , hoverinfo='text', opacity=opacity) # a dict of Plotly node attributes
    trace=dict(trace, **attrib)# concatenate the dict trace and attrib
    trace['marker']['size']=size
    trace['marker']['color']=color
    return trace`

The line `trace['marker']['color']=color` assigns the same color to all nodes.

If I replace this line by `trace['marker']['color']=random.randint(500)`, it will give a random color to each node.

I would like for each node to have a color predetermined by dictionary with nodes as keys and colors as values.

How might I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: just need to define `color` as a list of colors which are automatically indexed with the nodes.